# Want to blur my Image output without using Vectors (Shader Nodes)

Tags: node-editor, shaders, image, blur

I just want to blur my Image without using Vectors in Shader Editor because my Vector input slot is already occupied.

[image]

The result in the Viewport is the one which I want to be blurred. But, as I said earlier, I dont have place to play with Vector Inputs. Is there any other methods which I could follow to make the **Sharp Black and White Result** a bit blurred?

Here is the .blend File

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OVM29znyYKZ93eQZxWk9cIFvFFF-6HA1/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you can blur; The Voronoi pattern's edges, and the precipitation/temperature areas of effect. Place any vector-based blur before them, and it will blur them.

[image: blur nodes positions]

---

If you don't have one, here's a decent vector-based blur:

[image: example of vector-based blur node group]

Comment: I have Attached the Blend file..pls go through it.

Comment: So yup, it works, just a bit different that what I supposed. See Edit

Comment: Thank you........

Comment: Hi. In your provided decent blur node group, there is no **Grain Fac**

Comment: Oh right, it think I made this change later to more easily control the grain. I plugged a multiply node into the noise texture's scale, with the first input plugged in the group input as "grain fac" with a default value of 1, and the second value set to 1000 like the noise texture's scale originally was.